# react-native Is there any api can recognize my release is aab format or apk format?

Tags: react-native

I am building an react-native app.
I know there is api such as Platform.OS can recognize the the platform is android or ios.
Is there any api can recognize my release is aab format or apk format?

Answer (score 0):

We likely need more information in order to answer your question accurately.

I'd guess this is not possible since the .aab or .apk is the bundled code. React Native runs on the JS Core engine. I'm struggling to see why you would want to know this though within your application as you should be using the Android App Bundle OR submitting with the APK, not a mix of both.

Indeed in Google Play once you've enabled Managed Signing (to use the .aab) then I don't think you can go back to using the .apk files.